# ModelSearch Query error in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have two tables `project` and `workload`. I want show user in some project that added in Workload, and anothers member in this project (I called Team Member of that Project), too.

My idea is join 2 tables `project` and `workload` with `user_id` condition to take projects of user have `user_id`, then, from that will join with `workload` table again to take data from project of user have that user_id and user_id of team member will have that projects.

That my code in `WorkloadSearch.php`

```
public function searchWorkloadofUser($params) {
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $query = Workload::find()
        ->select(['workload.project_id', 'workload.commit_time', 'project.project_name', 'workload.from_date', 'workload.to_date', 'workload.workload_type', 'workload.comment'])
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'project', 'workload.project_id=project.id')
        ->where('workload.user_id = '.$user_id)->orderBy('project.project_name ASC')->distinct();
    $query->join('INNER JOIN','workload', 'project.id = workload.project_id')->distinct();
}
```

I don't understand why appeared error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'workload'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `workload`.`project_id`, `workload`.`commit_time`, `project`.`project_name`, `workload`.`from_date`, `workload`.`to_date`, `workload`.`workload_type`, `workload`.`comment` FROM `workload` INNER JOIN `project` ON workload.project_id=project.id INNER JOIN `workload` ON project.id = workload.project_id WHERE workload.user_id = 20) `c`
```

Comment: Use aliases for workload table in joins

Comment: Thanks, when I improve it, it run, but result can have that I want. I still don't understand why

Comment: The error apears because you use table `workload` twice in the query and mysql can't decide which fields to select from which of this two tables. When you use aliases you explain to mysql "who is who here" =)

Comment: `Workload::find()` - uses workload table and `$query->join('INNER JOIN','workload'` uses the same table. Just writing `$query->join('INNER JOIN','workload AS w'` and than using alias `w` should solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like the others said: You need an alias. Your error messages tells you:

```sql
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'workload'
```

This is beacause you joined your table `worload` to your `workload` table:

```php
$query = Workload::find() //your `workload` table
    ->select([
        ....
    ])
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'project p'], 'workload.project_id=p.id')
    ->where('workload.user_id = '.$user_id)
    ->orderBy('p.project_name ASC')
    ->distinct();

$query->join('INNER JOIN','workload', 'project.id = workload.project_id') //join the `workload` table to the `workload` table
    ->distinct();
```

When you want to join a table to itself, you have to define an alias at least for the joining table.

I would recommend you to quote the tablenames and columns whis is described in the Yii2 guide [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#quoting-table-and-column-names) and **do not** concat strings but bind params like it's described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#where) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#binding-parameters). This code should work for you (not tested):

```php
$query = Workload::find() //your `workload` table
    ->select([
        '{{workload}}.[[project_id]]', //quoting tablenames and columns
        '{{%workload}}.[[commit_time]]', //add '%' when you're using table prefix
        ...
    ])
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'project p'], 'workload.project_id=p.id')
    ->where('workload.user_id' = :user_id, [':user_id' => $user_id]) //You should bind params when use string format
    //or use hash format
    //->where(['workload.user_id' => $user_id])
    ...

$query->join('INNER JOIN','workload w2', 'project.id = w2.project_id') //Use the alias `w2` to  join the `workload` table to the `workload` table
    ->distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the user table an alias the second time you join to it

e.g.

```
SELECT workload.project_id, workload.commit_time, p.project_name, ...
FROM workload 
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = workload.project_id 
WHERE workload.user_id = '1'
```

Your solution should be (untested):

```
public function searchWorkloadofUser($params)
{
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $query = Workload::find()
        ->select(['workload.project_id', 'workload.commit_time', 'p.project_name', 'workload.from_date', 'workload.to_date', 'workload.workload_type', 'workload.comment'])
        ->join('INNER JOIN', 'project p'], 'workload.project_id=p.id')
        ->where('workload.user_id = '.$user_id)->orderBy('p.project_name ASC')->distinct();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test now

Comment: It still error. I use alias in `$query->join('INNER JOIN','workload as workloadTeam', 'project.id = workload.project_id')->distinct(); `  
it run but I have exactly result that I want

Comment: I think the problem is the second innerjoin. please make it more clear why you want to join workload twice.

Comment: I fixed with my way. By the way, I have new question about this. You can see it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278830/convert-from-query-to-modelsearch-of-yii2